# Stuck with angular routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My **app.js** looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('landingPage', [
    'ngRoute',
    'application.controllers',
    ...
])

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/home',
                controller: 'mainController'
            })
            .when('/sing_in', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/sing_in',
                controller: 'signInController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            })

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
    }
])
```

My `view`s directory like this:[image] (I am trying to migrate the server -- express -- side routing to angular, that's why I have so many pages, not just home).

And my routes on server side look like this:
module.exports = function(app) {

```
var api = App.route('Api')

var routes = App.route('Routes')

app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials)
app.get('/image/:id', routes.image)
app.get(new RegExp('^(?!api).*$'), routes.index)


app.get('/api/...', api.handleThis)
```

}

For some reason I am always redirected to `/`, because of the `otherwise` phrase on the anguar router. There are not calls to `/partials/sign_in`. Note that I tried to add a `/` in front of the `tempalteUrl`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Try `templateUrl: 'views/partials/home'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
templateUrl: 'partials/sing_in',
```

to this:

```
templateUrl: 'partials/sign_in',
```

---

Seems to be a typo in `sing` which has to be `sign`